# what happens when i click add to cart button i am facing some error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

What happens when i click add to cart button how to fix this error using laravel ?

Please see this error
Argument 5 passed to Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\E-commerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 245

https://flareapp.io/share/xmN6yEm0

**Controller**

```
        public  function addcart(Request $request)
        {
        Cart::add($request->productid,$request->product_name,$request->qty,$reques- 
        >product_image,$request->product_price);
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('successmessage','Items added successfully');
         }
```

**html view**

```
            <form action="{{route('cart.action')}}" method="post" class="product__options">
             {{ csrf_field() }}

            <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="{{$single_products->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="{{$single_products->product_name}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_image" value="{{$single_products- 
             >product_image}}">
             <input type="hidden" name="product_brand" value="{{$single_products->product_brand}}">
             <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="{{$single_products->product_price}}">

                <div class="form-group product__option">
                <label class="product__option-label" for="product-quantity">Quantity</label>
                <div class="product__actions">
                <div class="product__actions-item">
                <div class="input-number product__quantity">
                <input id="product-quantity" name="qty" class="input-number__input form-control 
                 form-control-lg" type="number" min="1" value="1">
                <div class="input-number__add"></div>
                <div class="input-number__sub"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__actions-item product__actions-item--addtocart">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="product__actions-item product__actions-item--wishlist">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-svg-icon btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wishlist">
                <svg width="16px" height="16px">
                <use xlink:href="{{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#wishlist-16')}}"></use>
                </svg>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="product__actions-item product__actions-item--compare">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-svg-icon btn-lg" data- 
                 toggle="tooltip" title="Compare">
                <svg width="16px" height="16px">
                <use xlink:href="{{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#compare-16')}}"></use>
                </svg>
                </button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: apparently argument 5 to `add` is supposed to be an array and you are passing a string ... as per the error you need to pass an array not a string

Comment: You might want not add product image, and make price your 4th argument. According to https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

,Actually the `Cart::add` method takes price on fourth parameter and fifth parameter is for options where you can pass array of options
for example:

```
Cart::add(['id' => '293ad', 'name' => 'Product 1', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 9.99, 'options' => ['size' => 'large']]);
```

What you can do is modify your function like this and it should work, hopefully:

```
public function addcart(Request $request){
    $image = [$request->product_image];
    Cart::add($request->productid,$request->product_name,$request->qty,$request->product_price,$image);
    return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('successmessage','Items added successfully');
}
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Anytime and it's my pleasure to help you. Can you upvote my answer ?